# INDEX, MATCH function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in 2 columns (H,I). I want to add 2 more columns (K,L) What I want is when I write word 'red' into a  K column, that it automatical writes in cloumn L the number or whatever is in that cell next to the 'red' word from H column.

[image]

Comment: it isn't `If` that you need, rather you need a combination of `index` and `match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing has been asked numerous times on Stack Overflow, though it is sometimes hard to know how to find the answer when you don't know what to look for. In any event, a combination of `Index` and `Match` can often be used when you need to lookup data based on some criteria. See [this](http://exceluser.com/blog/465/excels-best-lookup-method-index-match.html) for a discussion. In your case, put the formula

```
=INDEX(H:H,MATCH(K1,I:I,0))
```

in cell L1 and copy down.

Comment: Ok, I got it. 0 is for match type https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

Comment: Is it possible to use OR here to search in two columns and if one is empty, use other one... like `=INDEX(H:H,MATCH(K1,I:I,0))OR(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(K1,N:N,0)))`?